# How to catch close banner event in Google adMob on iOS?

Tags: ios, admob

Can't find in docs how to catch "close banner" event when you push little "cross button" in down-left corner:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way. Why do you need to know when it closes? Maybe there's an alternative way to do what you want...

Comment: @Nik I want to update my UI when the user decides to close the ad. I want to use this free extra space then. I saw this behaviour with adMob in mobile site in safari and I think it's possible regardless of the platform.

Comment: I don't think the ad actually goes away. The space is still taken up, only it doesn't show an ad anymore.

Comment: This is the short video to understand what I'm talking about https://www.dropbox.com/s/501n2dbn5tr4wtq/IMG_4811.MOV?dl=0

Comment: Hmmm... I've never actually seen that in an app. Sorry, but I don't know how to help now

Comment: Use auto layout and it will handle resizing your view for you.